# Log4J API to log long messages in temporary files

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

Am trying to understand if there are any best practices/utilities/out of the box functionality for logging messages that are quite long (typically json file responses/xmls/CSVs etc).

While logging as part of my application I do something like

```
log.info("Incompatible order found {}", order.asJson())
```

The problem being that the asJson() representation could be pretty long. In the log files the actual json is only relevant say 1% of the time. So it is important enough to retain but big enough to make me lose focus when I am trawling through logs.

Is there anyway I can could do something like

```
log.info("Incompatible order found, file dumped at {}", SomeUtility.dumpString(order.asJson()));
```

where the utility dumps the file into a location consistent with other log files and then in my log file I can see the following

```
Incompatible order found, file dumped at /abc/your/log/location/tmpfiles/xy23nmg
```

Key things to note being

1. It would be preferable to simply use the existing logging api to somehow configure this so that the location of these temp files are the same as log itself this way it goes through the cleanup cycle after N days etc just like the actual log files.
2. I can obviously write something but I am keen on existing utilities or features if already available withing log4j
3. I am aware that when logs such as these are imported into analysis systems like Splunk then only the filenames will be present without the actual files and this is okay.

Answer (score 1):

(Suggestion was given based on logback instead of log4j2.  However I believe similar facilities exists in log4j2)

In Logback, there is a facility called SiftingAppender, which allow separate appender (e.g. file appender) to be created according to some discriminator (e.g. in MDC).

So, by configuring an appender (e.g. orderDetailAppender) which separates file based on a discriminator (e.g. by putting order ID in MDC), and make use of a separate logger to connect to the appender, this should give you the result you want:

pseudo code:

logback config:

```
  <appender name="ORDER_DETAIL_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <!-- use MDC disciminator by default, you may choose/develop other appropriate discrimator -->
    <sift>
      <appender name="ORDER-DETAIL-${ORDER_ID}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
          ....
      </appender>
    </sift>
  </appender>
  <logger name="ORDER_DETAIL_LOGGER">
     <appender-ref name="ORDER_DETAIL_APPENDER"/>
  </logger>
```

and your code looks like:

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourClass.class); // logger you use normally
Logger orderDetailLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ORDER_DETAIL_LOGGER");
.....

MDC.put("ORDER_ID", order.getId());
logger.warn("something wrong in order {}. Find the file in separate file", order.getId());
orderDetailLogger.warn("Order detail:\n{}", order.getJson());
// consider making order.getJson() an lambda, or wrap the line with logger 
// level checking, to avoid json construction even not required to log
MDC.remove("ORDER_ID");
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to use a separate logger for the JSON dump, and configure that logger to put its output in a different file.

As an example:

```
private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();
private static final Logger jsonLog = LogManager.getLogger("jsondump");

...

log.info("Incompatible order found, id = {}", order.getId());
jsonLog.info("Incompatible order found, id = {}, JSON = {}",
        order.getId(), order.asJson());
```

Then, configure the logger named `jsondump` to go to a separate file, possibly with a separate rotation schedule. Make sure to set `additivity` to `false` for the JSON logger, so that messages sent to that logger won't be sent to the root logger as well. See [Additivity](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity)
 in the Log4J docs for details.

Example (XML configuration, Log4J 2):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
  <Appenders>
    <!-- By setting only filePattern, not fileName, all log files
         will use the pattern for naming. Files will be rotated once
         an hour, since that's the most specific unit in the
         pattern. -->
    <RollingFile name="LogFile" filePattern="app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH}00.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c [%t] %m %ex%n"/>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
      </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    <!-- See comment for appender named "LogFile" above. -->
    <RollingFile name="JsonFile" filePattern="json-%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH}00.log">
      <!-- Omitting logger name for this appender, as it's only used by
           one logger. -->
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p [%t] %m %ex%n"/>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
      </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <!-- Note that additivity="false" to prevent JSON dumps from being
         sent to the root logger as well. -->
    <Logger name="jsondump" level="debug" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="JsonFile"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="LogFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```